# R - Why does a data.frame turn columns consisting only of numbers into a character vector?

Tags: r, dataframe, character, numeric

Here is a simple dataframe I made, the data is originally in a pdf which is why I entered the column names first and then the rows like so.

```
skupni_indeksi <- data.frame(Proizvod =NA, Mjerna_jedinica=NA,Količine_2007=0,Količine_2008=0,Cijene_2007=0,Cijene_2008=0,stringsAsFactors = F)
skupni_indeksi[1,] <- c("A", "komad", 10, 12, 25, 30)
skupni_indeksi[2,] <-c("B", "litra", 30, 40, 40, 40)
skupni_indeksi[3,] <-c("C", "m2", 20, 15, 60, 72)
```

I know there are other ways of inputting such data, but my question concerns the behaviour of dataframes. Look at the column Cijene_2007, for example. It is originally a single number, and the new rows all place numbers into that column. Why is the column of a character type, when checking with str(skupni_indeksi)?

I found a manual solution to turn desired columns into numeric, simply:

`skupni_indeksi[,3:6] <- sapply(skupni_indeksi[,3:6], as.numeric)`

which fixes the issue. Could I have done something different in the first place to not need this line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`c("A", "komad", 10, 12, 25, 30)` is a vector. A vector can have only one class.

Since you have numbers and characters mixed it turns the number to characters.

```
class(c("A", "komad", 10, 12, 25, 30))
#[1] "character"
```

You are filling the dataframe in a row-wise fashion. Usually, it is better to fill them in column-wise so that such data conversion do not take place.

Comment: Ah, I see, that makes sense - the row character vector means everything inside it is a character, no matter what the resulting columns look like.
The reason for a row-wise fill is because I couldn't copy and paste column-wise from a pdf :)